# Prevent triggering jQuery .click event by hitting enter

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".plus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //add input box
    $(".list").append('<div class="item"><select name=selection[]>...select options here...</select><a href="#" class="Remove">remove</a></div>');
  });

  //user click on remove text
  $(".list").on("click", ".remove", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
  <div>
    <button class="plus">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list"></div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txt">
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

This code is used to add (click .plus button)/remove (click .remove link) rows of select boxes in a dynamic form and works flawlessly. The form also contains a search input field (name="txt"), which is not part of the .list class. If I type stuff in this input field and hit Enter (which should submit the form), apparently this is handled as a click event of the .plus button and a new row is added instead of submitting the form. If I submit the form via mouse click everything is ok. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Your form is treating the `.plus` button as a submit button because it does not have a type (default action of a form). However, you've called `event.preventDefault()` so the form isn't submitted, but your row is added instead.

There's a few ways to prevent this; one way is to simply add `type="button"` to your first button to differentiate it from the `submit` type.

```
<button class="plus" type="button">+</button>
```